# Sending Dynamic file path from Azure Databricks Code to Azure Logic apps for email attachments

Tags: python, azure-logic-apps, email-attachments, azure-databricks, dynamicparameters

Hi I am new to logic apps. I have a python code for sending mail with attachments using Azure Logic Apps. When I provide a static file path in Get Blob Content the mail is working fine with the attachment. But when I am trying to the send the file path dynamically from azure databricks it is not receiving at the get blob content in logic app. I have also tried few examples using initialise variables but it is not working.

```
import requests

def send_email(_to, _subject, _body, file):
  
  email_body = "{0} <br><br><br> <h6> Hi Hello World </h6>".format(_body)
  
  task = { "body_data_1": email_body , "subject_name_1": _subject , "email_to_list_1": _to, "attach" : file }
  logic_app_post_url = 'https://prod-27.centralindia.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/*****'
  resp = requests.post(logic_app_post_url, json=task)
  print(resp.status_code)
  if resp.status_code == 202:
    print('Email Sent!')

email_to = "abc@outlook.com"
email_subject = "Testing Logic App Send Mail with Dynamic File"
email_body = "Hi This is a test mail Dynamic"
file_path = "/super-store/output/orders/_SUCCESS"
send_email(email_to, email_subject, email_body, file_path)
```

**Logic App Design**

[image]

**Logic App Run Error Details**

[image]

**HTTP Input**
[image]

**HTTP Output**
[image]

**Get Blob Content Input**
[image]

**Get Blob Content Output**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have observed `Get Blob Content (V2)` is being used to send the attachments dynamically from azure Data bricks. Instead, we suggest using **Get Blob Content using Path(V2)** connector.

Wherein `Get Blob Content (V2)` connector will *retrieve* **blob contents using id** and `Get Blob Content using Path (V2)` connector *retrieves* **blob contents using path**.

Example with snippets:

[image]
[image]

Result:

[image]